# Import from my package recognized by PyCharm but not by command line

Tags: python, python-3.6

I've created the following package tree:

```
/main_package
    /child_package
    version.py
```

where version.py contains a single string variable (VERSION)

Inside my script in child package I'm importing version.py by the following line:

```
from main_package.version import VERSION
```

While I'm running the code from PyCharm everything works great, however when I'm running the code via the command line I'm getting the following error message:

```
C:\Users\usr\PycharmProjects\project\main_package\child_package>python script.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "script.py", line 2, in <module>
from main_package.version import VERSION
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'main_package'
```

I've found in the internet that I might need to add my package to the python path, however it doesn't seems to work for me

Comment: Already did that, each directory contains empty __init__.py file

Comment: Do you have a setup.py file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PyCharm sets the Python Path at the root of the project (by default). To mimic this in a quick'n'dirty fashion, you just need to do this once in your shell session before invoking `python whatever`:

```
set PYTHONPATH=C:\Users\usr\PycharmProjects\project
```

Answer (score 1):

**The pythonic way** is to have a `setup.py` file to install your project in the system (check [python Minimal Structure](http://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/minimal.html)):

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(name='main_package',
      version='0.1',
      description='main package',
      license='MIT',
      packages=['main_package'],
      zip_safe=False)
```

Then you install it as follow:

- `python setup.py install` for global installation

OR

- `python setup.py develop` for local installation in editable mode

Comment: In the system or in a virtual environment if you can't or don't want to install globally.

Comment: Yeah of course it depends. But even independently of that you can use editable mode `python setup.py develop` for local installation.

Comment: It works.

python setup.py develop

it works perfectly thank you so much